# The Traveling Salesman algorithm bug

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have tried to make an algorithm solving the traveling salesman problem as follows:

```
%main function:
[siz, ~] = size(table);
done(1:siz) = false;
done(1) = true;

[dist, path] = bruteForce(table, done, 1);
```

function bruteForce:

```
function [distance, path] = bruteForce(table, done, index)

size = length(done);

dmin = inf;
distance = 0;
path = [];

%finding minimum distance
for i = 1:size
    if ~done(i)
        done(i) = true;
       %iterating through all nodes using recursion
       [d, p] = bruteForce(table, done, i);
       if (d < dmin)
           dmin = d;
           path = [i p];
           distance = dmin + table(i, index);
       end

       %freing the node again 
       done(i) = false;
    end
end

if distance == 0
    distance = table(1, index);
    path = 1;
end
```

Unfortunately, for the following matrix:

```
 B = [0   29  20  21  16  31  100 12  4   31  18;
      29  0   15  29  28  40  72  21  29  41  12;
      20  15  0   15  14  25  81  9   23  27  13;
      21  29  15  0   4   12  92  12  25  13  25;
      16  28  14  4   0   16  94  9   20  16  22;
      31  40  25  12  16  0   95  24  36  3   37;
      100 72  81  92  94  95  0   90  101 99  84;
      12  21  9   12  9   24  90  0   15  25  13;
      4   29  23  25  20  36  101 15  0   35  18;
      31  41  27  13  16  3   99  25  35  0   38;
      18  12  13  25  22  37  84  13  18  38  0];
```

Instead of getting the expected result:

```
1-8-5-4-10-6-3-7-2-11-9-1 = 253km
```

I get:

```
1-8-11-3-4-6-10-5-9-2-7-1 = 271km
```

Could you help me find the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If brute force is a must and speed is no issue, then just use the perms function for the number of cities. This allows for an easy implementation:

```
table = [0   29  20  21  16  31  100 12  4   31  18;
  29  0   15  29  28  40  72  21  29  41  12;
  20  15  0   15  14  25  81  9   23  27  13;
  21  29  15  0   4   12  92  12  25  13  25;
  16  28  14  4   0   16  94  9   20  16  22;
  31  40  25  12  16  0   95  24  36  3   37;
  100 72  81  92  94  95  0   90  101 99  84;
  12  21  9   12  9   24  90  0   15  25  13;
  4   29  23  25  20  36  101 15  0   35  18;
  31  41  27  13  16  3   99  25  35  0   38;
  18  12  13  25  22  37  84  13  18  38  0];
[siz, ~] = size(table);

[bp, b] = bruteForce(table, siz)

function [bestpath, best] = bruteForce(table, siz)
p      = perms(1:siz);
[r, c] = size(p);
best   = inf;
for i = 1:r
    path = p(i, :);
    dist = distCalculatorReturn(table, path);    
    if dist < best
        best     = dist;
        bestpath = path;
    end    
end
bestpath = [bestpath, bestpath(1)];
end

function [totaldist] = distCalculatorReturn(distMatrix, proposedPath)
dist = 0;
i    = 1;
while i ~= length(proposedPath)
    dist = dist + distMatrix(proposedPath(i),proposedPath(i+1));
    i    = i+1;
end
dist = dist + distMatrix(proposedPath(1), proposedPath(end));      
totaldist = dist;
end
```

This yields the answer you are looking for. However, if you are only solving problems of that size, why not apply a standard simulated annealing. This gives much faster solution times and should solve the problem size consistently:

```
table = [0   29  20  21  16  31  100 12  4   31  18;
      29  0   15  29  28  40  72  21  29  41  12;
      20  15  0   15  14  25  81  9   23  27  13;
      21  29  15  0   4   12  92  12  25  13  25;
      16  28  14  4   0   16  94  9   20  16  22;
      31  40  25  12  16  0   95  24  36  3   37;
      100 72  81  92  94  95  0   90  101 99  84;
      12  21  9   12  9   24  90  0   15  25  13;
      4   29  23  25  20  36  101 15  0   35  18;
      31  41  27  13  16  3   99  25  35  0   38;
      18  12  13  25  22  37  84  13  18  38  0];

[path, dist] = tsp(table, length(table))  

function [path, dist] = tsp(D, n)


L = 40*n;       

epsi = 1e-9;   

x = randperm(n);
fx = distCalculatorReturn(D, x);


T = 1000000;
while T > epsi
    for i=1:L
        num1 = 1 + floor(rand*n);
        num2 = 1 + floor(rand*n);
        while num1 == num2
            num1 = 1 + floor(rand*n);
        end
        y = x;
        swap1 = y(num1);
        y(num1) = y(num2);
        y(num2) = swap1;


        fy = distCalculatorReturn(D,y);
        if fy < fx
            x = y;
            fx = fy;
        elseif rand < exp(-(fy - fx)/T)
            x = y;
            fx = fy;
        end

    end

    T = 0.9*T;
end
path  = [x, x(1)];
dist  = fx;

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you come up with the constants `T, epsi, L` for `simulated annealing`, though?

Comment: Simulated annealing mimics the process of annealing. So you need to start with an arbitrarily large enough temperature T. epsi is just the tolerance control for the while loop (will control how many iterations are done). L is the length of the markov chain at each set temperature. Values are somewhat default. As with all metaheuristics if they don't work out the box then you will need to experiment to find optimal parameters. Those parameters and basic swapping seem more than good enough for TSP problems that size.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compute the distance for each possible path (as *bruteForce* suggests). Instead it always starts at node `1` and from there goes always to the node that is closest to the current node. As your example shows, that does not necessarily lead to the overall shortest path. You will need to go through all possible paths to be sure you find the optimum.

Here is my go at your problem:

```
% distance matrix
B  = [0   29  20  21  16  31  100 12  4   31  18;
      29  0   15  29  28  40  72  21  29  41  12;
      20  15  0   15  14  25  81  9   23  27  13;
      21  29  15  0   4   12  92  12  25  13  25;
      16  28  14  4   0   16  94  9   20  16  22;
      31  40  25  12  16  0   95  24  36  3   37;
      100 72  81  92  94  95  0   90  101 99  84;
      12  21  9   12  9   24  90  0   15  25  13;
      4   29  23  25  20  36  101 15  0   35  18;
      31  41  27  13  16  3   99  25  35  0   38;
      18  12  13  25  22  37  84  13  18  38  0];

% compute all possible paths assuming we always start at node 1
nNodes  = size(B,1);
paths   = perms(2:nNodes);
nPaths  = size(paths,1);
paths   = [ones(nPaths,1) paths ones(nPaths,1)]; % start and finish tour at node 1

% with a random start point:
% paths   = perms(1:nNodes);
% paths   = [perms(1:nNodes) paths(:,1)];

% compute overall distance for each path
distance = inf;
for idx=1:nPaths
    from    = paths(idx,1:end-1);
    to      = paths(idx,2:end);
    d       = sum(diag(B(from,to)));
    if d<distance
        distance = d;
        optPath  = paths(idx,:);
    end
end
```

This leads to the following result:

```
optPath  = [1 9 11 2 7 3 6 10 4 5 8 1]
distance = 253
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot! I am not sure, though, I understand why my algorithm goes only to the closest node. Note that when calling `bruteForce` recursively, it is not returning the distance to the next node, but rather the minimum sum of the following distances (depth first)